# How to properly configure upstream identity providers for Federation Gateway architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

We are writing an ASP.NET core 2.2 web application which is basically an identity provider implemented by using identity server 4. So, **this question is related to the identity provider application itself, not to the client application using the identity provider to sign in and access an API**. We are developing against identity server 4 version `2.5.3` (the latest stable version available).

We have used the [identity server 4 quickstart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI) in order to provide a user interface.

The architecture we are implementing is the [federation gateway](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/federation_gateway.html), so we don't need to handle local users: the only way for a user to authenticate is using one of the configured upstream identity providers.

Each deploy of this application will be able to configure the upstream identity providers dynamically; the idea is being compatible with any identity provider compliant with the open id connect protocol.

The high level plan is writing what follows inside the `Startup.ConfigureServices` method:

```
var builder = services.AddAuthentication();

foreach (var provider in configuredProviders)
{
    builder.AddOpenIdConnect(provider.Key, provider.Name, options =>
      {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
        options.SaveTokens = true;

        options.ClientId = provider.ClientId;
        options.Authority = provider.Authority;
        options.ClientSecret = provider.ClientSecret;
        options.MetadataAddress = provider.MetadataAddress;

        options.CallbackPath = $"/signin-oidc-{provider.Key}";
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = $"/signout-callback-oidc-{provider.Key}";

        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
          NameClaimType = "name",
          RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
      });
}
```

We want to keep this code **the bare minimum** needed to configure the external providers for identity server 4. We have started from [this sample](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html) and added the different options incrementally.

We have the following questions:

- is it really needed to specify **both** the `Authority` and the
  `MetadataAddress` ? Can we avoid specifying the `Authority` and leave
  the `MetadataAddress` only ?
- we have found out that the different    providers must have different
  values for the properties    `CallbackPath` and 
  `SignedOutCallbackPath` (otherwise it doesn't    work). Is it fine to
  set these properties the way we did ? Can we set    them to whatever
  unique value ? Is there any validation rule applied    to them (apart
  from being valid URL path) ?
- how can we configure the    provider so    that after logging out
  from it the user agent is    redirected to the    home page of our
  identity provider application ? We    have tried to    set `options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "/"`, but it seems to be ignored. After logging out from the external provider we are redirected to a page asking us if we are sure to logging out from identity server. We are not able to be redirected to the home page.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

- The `Authority` is the the identity of the token service. You have to
  specify it anyway. You may skip the `MetadataAddress` when it has the
  default value.
- The `CallbackPath`es are the endpoints, OIdC middleware creates for
  you for each particular external provider to handle the callbacks
  with correct settings, and your way of configuring it is absolutely
  correct.
- When using the quickstart UI, after been logged out, you come to the
  `Account/Logout` action and [LoggedOut](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Views/Account/LoggedOut.cshtml) view. You can customize it up to
  your needs, but it handles `PostLogoutRedirectUri` out of the box... when you log out properly, i.e. providing a valid `id_token_hint` and `post_logout_redirect_uri` itself, as described in the [doc](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/endsession.html).